# config of cisco 2950 switches

Tags: design

i have a cisco sw 48 port and 2 are gb ports.
i have 4 servers
and most of the ports are directly connected to the users i.e access port and some are going to the tp link switches and some are going to access points modems/router (director has a separate router/modem to which they are connected speed to them is compulsary )
and some are going to the printers.
so whats the best config recomended for best possible result?

Comment: This question is too broad. We need a lot more information to even guess. For example, a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Also, we would need to understand the traffic and traffic patterns. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest: None. Cisco 2950 have reached there end of life date years ago. There are very likely many many security bugs and no updates. Do not use them (in an production environment).

Comment: Thanks for ur time sir. its not that much of a productive environment and all we want is the smooth connectivity.